# Bootstrap & Wordpress - Nothing happens

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I'm trying to use a Bootstrap Modal, and I want it to appear after a click (onclick method).

Right now I have this

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
      
       $("#cancelPObtn").on("click", function(){ $("#error-dialog").modal();});
          
    });
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- BELOW ON MY WORDPRESS POST   -->
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" id="cancelPObtn" data-toggle="modal" href="#error-dialog">Yes, cancel it</a>
 <div class="modal hide fade" id="error-dialog">
   <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</a>
        <h3>Cancel Purchase Order?</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-modal btn-cancel"  data-dismiss="modal">Yes, cancel it</a>
       <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Nevermind</a>
   </div>
 </div>
<!-- I HAVE THE JAVASCRIPT ON MY POST TOO, USING <script type="text/javascript"> -->
```

So, it appears to be working, everywhere, but on my Wordpress post I can't make it work! I've added the JS + CSS Files from Bootstrap on my header.php

What could be the issue here?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you see any error message in the browser Dev console when you click on the button?

Comment: @IndieRok Nope, the button appears just like you can see when running the snippet, but when I press it nothing happens!

Answer (score 3):

You should read up on [enqueuing scripts and styles in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). WordPress has it's own way of including the script files and the stylesheets that you should familiarize yourself with. A lot of times, what ends up happening is either the files aren't included correctly, or in the wrong order, or without the dependencies they might need. Adding the links directly to header.php is strongly discouraged.

Comment: in addition to using enqueue for the bootstrap scripts, you should use it to add the javascript function that you wrote with the click function as well. It's a pain, but it's the wordpress way. (may be worth adding to the answer, @ceili)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I always used Wordpress, but I've been trying to code my own CMS but I'm still learning PHP, JS and others. I found bootstrap really easy to use, but still learning.
I'll try and see if I can make it work, once again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using `wp_enqueue_script` as recommended above, I would ensure you're writing non-conflicting jQuery, as WordPress plugins sometimes come bundled with their own JavaScript libraries, which can cause issues.

See below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('#cancelPObtn').click(function() {
      $('#error-dialog').modal();
    });
  }
</script>
```

Also, WordPress is probably calling its own instance of jQuery, so you can use `window.jQuery` to test before including your own, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>');
</script>
```

**Resources:**

- [jQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict)
- [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://www.github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/index.html)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that at all. I still didn't fix that issue, the button appears but when I press it nothing happens, I've tried everything I can think off, but no luck...

Comment: Using your browser console (**Ctrl+Shift+J** in Chrome, **Ctrl+Shift+K** in Firefox), type the following:

`jQuery('#error-dialog').modal();`

Does your modal appear?